# How can I implement a K-Map with negative feedback?

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra

How do you describe a boolean function using a K-Map in such a way that the boolean function depends on the previous value of this function?

Comment: use previous output as one of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the present output depends on previous output, then use the previous output as as one of the variable in truth table and K-map.

Take JK flipflop as an example:

```
-------------------
J  K  Qn    Qn+1
-------------------
0  0   0     0
0  0   1     1
0  1   0     0
0  1   1     0
1  0   0     1
1  0   1     1
1  1   0     1
1  1   1     0
------------------
```

[image]